# NextJs 13 - Edge causing pages to return 500 (Internal Error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently following the NextJs guide for setting up the runtime to use Edge, to try and take advantage or the performance benefits. However, I do not seem to be having any luck. I am getting a 500 response. I have tried to add this globally and per page, but all I get is the same error, with

```
"[TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'registered')]"
```

in the terminal.

My current setup : NextJs 13.0.7 (latest as of today)

[image]

[image: File using edge]

Those are some images of the setup using edge.